# how do i open a specific collapse accordian when using a anchor component in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am new to react and ant design, I want to open the specific accordion when clicking on to a specific place. The idea is that when I am clicking on the specific place the page roll over to that accordion( i am achieving this using **Anchor Component of antd**), but not opening that accordion. Here is my code where I am using anchor and collapse componenet. How do I proceed so that when i click on the specific div the page roll over to that place and accordion gets open?

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Timeline, Anchor, Collapse } from 'antd';
const Panel = Collapse.Panel;
import FlowData from './data';
import './LearningPathFlowchart.scss';

function callback(key: any) {
  console.log(key);
}

const { Link } = Anchor;

interface ICollapseState {
  isOpen?: boolean;
}

interface Idata {
  href: string;
  title: string | React.ReactNode;
  content: string;
}
const text = `
  A dog is a type of domesticated animal.
  Known for its loyalty and faithfulness,
  it can be found as a welcome guest in many households across the world.
`;

export default class LearningPathFlowchart extends React.Component<{}, ICollapseState> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
    };
  }

  public onClick() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  }
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card hoverable style={{ width: '300px', margin: '0px auto', height: '800px' }}>
          <div className='learning-path__flowchart'>
            <Timeline>
              <Anchor affix={false} offsetTop={10} onClick={() => this.onClick}>
                {FlowData.data.map((value: Idata, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={index}>
                      <Timeline.Item >
                        <Link href={value.href} title={value.title}>{value.content}</Link>
                      </Timeline.Item>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </Anchor>
            </Timeline>
          </div>

        </Card>
        <div>
          <Collapse onChange={callback}>
            <Panel key='panel1' id='Panel1' header='This is panel header 1' >
              <p>{text}</p>
            </Panel>
            <Panel key='panel2' id='Panel3' header='This is panel header 2' >
              <p>{text}</p>
            </Panel>
            <Panel key='panel3' id='Panel4' header='This is panel header 3'>
              <p>{text}</p>
            </Panel>
          </Collapse>,
        <div style={{ height: '500px' }}>Testing</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to open the **Collapse** on click of the **Anchor** then you have to make slight changes in your code.
First of all, the Collapse of antd has a property **activeKey** which accepts the Keys of the active Panel (link: [antd collapse API](https://ant.design/components/collapse/#API)),
so you can simply pass the key on the click event of an item in the Anchor.

In your case, you can pass the FlowData map index as the key for the Collapse and make sure to change the Panel key similar to FlowData map index (0-lastIndexValue).

Here are the changes in your code you might need to do.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Timeline, Anchor, Collapse } from 'antd';
const Panel = Collapse.Panel;
import FlowData from './data';
import './LearningPathFlowchart.scss';

function callback(key: any) {
  console.log(key);
}

const { Link } = Anchor;

interface ICollapseState {
  isOpen?: boolean;
}

interface Idata {
  href: string;
  title: string | React.ReactNode;
  content: string;
}
const text = `
  A dog is a type of domesticated animal.
  Known for its loyalty and faithfulness,
  it can be found as a welcome guest in many households across the world.
`;

export default class LearningPathFlowchart extends React.Component<{}, ICollapseState> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      collapseActiveKey: '0'
    };
  }

  public onClick() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  }

  public setCollapseActiveKey(index) {
    this.setState({ collapseActiveKey: index.toString() });
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card hoverable style={{ width: '300px', margin: '0px auto', height: '800px' }}>
          <div className='learning-path__flowchart'>
            <Timeline>
              <Anchor affix={false} offsetTop={10} onClick={() => this.onClick}>
                {FlowData.data.map((value: Idata, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={index} onClick={_ => this.setCollapseActiveKey(index)}>
                      <Timeline.Item >
                        <Link href={value.href} title={value.title}>{value.content}</Link>
                      </Timeline.Item>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </Anchor>
            </Timeline>
          </div>

        </Card>
        <div>
          <Collapse onChange={callback}  activeKey={[this.state.collapseActiveKey]}>
            <Panel key='1' id='Panel1' header='This is panel header 1' >
              <p>{text}</p>
            </Panel>
            <Panel key='2' id='Panel3' header='This is panel header 2' >
              <p>{text}</p>
            </Panel>
            <Panel key='3' id='Panel4' header='This is panel header 3'>
              <p>{text}</p>
            </Panel>
          </Collapse>,
        <div style={{ height: '500px' }}>Testing</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```